# How can this query be ordered by the number of keyword matches?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to search the following `Episode` model by keywords.  `Episode` has a many-to-many relationship `_key_words` linking an episode to `EpisodeKeyword`.  `EpisodeKeyword` represents a word that can be searched for.

```
class Episode(db.Model):
    _key_words = db.relationship('EpisodeKeyword',
        secondary = KeywordEpisode,
        primaryjoin = _id==KeywordEpisode.c.feed_id,
        secondaryjoin = EpisodeKeyword._id==KeywordEpisode.c.keyword_id,
        backref = db.backref('episodes', lazy = 'dynamic'),
        lazy = 'dynamic')


class EpisodeKeyword(db.Model):
    '''
    A keyword for an Episode
    '''
    __table_args__ = {'mysql_engine': 'InnoDB', 'mysql_charset': 'utf8mb4'}

    DB_MAX_WORD_LENGTH = 30
    _id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    _word = db.Column(db.String(DB_MAX_WORD_LENGTH), index = True, unique=True)


KeywordEpisode = db.Table('episode_keywords',
        db.Column('feed_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('episode._id'),index = True),
        db.Column('keyword_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('episode_keyword._id'),index = True)
    )
```

The search term is split to get a list of keywords to search:

```
user_input = 'oct 2014'
search_keywords = ['oct', '2014']
```

I can get a list of results using:

```
results = db.session.query(Episode).filter(EpisodeKeyword._word.in_(words)).join(Episode._key_words).join(Episode).all()
```

However, I also want to order the results by the count of the matched keywords.  For example, if Episode._key_words has both 'oct' and '2014' it should come before items with only one keyword matched.  What is the query that will accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subquery to filter and count the keywords, then join that to the final query.

```
# split the query into a list
search = 'oct 2014'
words = search.strip().split()

# use an unnest subquery instead of directly passing the list to in_
# this is for performance reasons for large lists of keywords
words_tab = db.session.query(db.func.unnest(words).label('word')).subquery()

# count the words that match for each episode as a subquery
# this also does the filtering since we're doing the join here
words_q = db.session.query(
    Episode.id,
    db.func.count(Episode.id).label('words')
).join(Episode._key_words
).filter(EpisodeKeyword._word.in_(words_tab)
).group_by(Episode.id
).subquery()

# join on the word query and order by its counts
results = Episode.query.join(
    (words_q, words_q.c.id == Episode.id)
).order_by(words_q.c.words.desc()
).all()
```